# Como imprimir omitiendo las columnas vacías en PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy programando la página de mi empresa y tenemos los productos en una base de datos sql, pero unos productos tendrán dos características y otros cinco.
No quiero imprimir las columnas vacías. Quisiera que se omitan los vacíos y seguir con el código. ¿Como lo hago?

Tengo este avance:

```
<?php

//REcIBIR VARIABLE
$var1=($_GET['variable']);

/*
if (empty($var1))
{
    echo "VAriable vacia";
}
else
{
    echo "Vaiable con valor";   
}
*/

$sql = "SELECT id, modelo, descripcion, imagen FROM productos WHERE categoria='$var1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Modelo: ".$row["modelo"]."Descripcion :".$row["descripcion"]."<img src=".$row["imagen"].">"."<br>";
    }
    {
    }}else
    {
        echo "Sin resultados";
    }

echo "Hola";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Hola Raul Cacacho, Enrique Manzano y user3286786. Gracias por ayudarme. Hasta ahorita revise esta comunidad. Perdon por la tradanza y le agradezco mucho. Dios los bendice... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con añadir una condicion dentro del bucle que recorre los datos recogidos de la base de datos valdría, en este caso solo te imprimiría los datos que tengan el ID

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if($row["id"] && $row["id"]!=""){
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Modelo: ".$row["modelo"]."Descripcion :".$row["descripcion"]."<img src=".$row["imagen"].">"."<br>";
  }
}
```

también valdría con modificar la consulta para que no te de datos vacíos añadiendo `IS NOT NULL` al campo que quieres que no esté vacío

```
$sql = "SELECT id, modelo, descripcion, imagen FROM productos WHERE 
categoria='$var1' and id IS NOT NULL";
```

Comment: Es posible que id sea una clave primaria y seguramente sea un int con auto_incremento como se suele hacer, con lo cual aunque haya un registro vacío lo que siempre va a tener es su clave, en vez de comprobar la clave id, mejor que la condición en php sea referente a los otros campos del registro, pero quitando ese pequeño matiz, sí esa sería una buena solución.

Comment: Claro eso tendrá que poner los campos que el necesite ya que puede que tenga algunos campos que no sean obligatorios y puedan estar vacíos por lo que esos no debería añadirlos al condicional, sin más información no se puede saber